# Tkinter: How to get ALL widgets under the mouse cursor?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm trying to create a simple drag-and-drop interface in Tkinter using the canvas. However, I've hit a snag:

The event binds 'enter' and 'leave' seem to only work for the TOP-most widget under the cursor. E.g., I wrote this bit of code to try and recognize when the cursor is over the 'board' space or not:

```
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 1250, 750, fill = 'grey', tag = 'Board')
    self.canvas.tag_bind('Board', "<Enter>", self.on_board)
    self.canvas.tag_bind('Board', "<Leave>", self.off_board)
    self.mouse_on_board = False
    
def on_board(self, event):
    self.mouse_on_board = True

def off_board(self, event):
    self.mouse_on_board = False
```

But when the cursor enters a draggable item on the board (e.g. a canvas.create_image() image drawn on top of the 'board' rectangle) this is treated as the cursor leaving the board widget. Whereas for my purpose, I want the code to recognize it is still over the board (just over another widget which is itself drawn over the board).

Is there a simple way in Tkinter to know whether the cursor is on top of a widget REGARDLESS of whether there are any other widgets stacked above or beneath it?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: you can use `.bbox` to get the coordinates of the board and check if mouse is in those coordinates using `<Motion>` event that is bound to canvas

Comment: Hi and thanks again, Matiis! I was hoping there might be a less cumbersome way, but using bbox works to get the effect I want, thanks!

Comment: @Matiiss Great answer - could you actually make it an answer? (If not, would you mind I do it?)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel you're free to make it an answer, it's been a while since I have used `tkinter`, so I am a bit rusty. Just maybe don't do any unconventional stuff, like using star imports, ha ha... I'm serious.